# Arduino fast ADC sampling--which burst control is best?

Tags: adc

If one wants to do quick bursts of free-running ADC conversions, should one pause and restart using:

The ADC enable bit: `bitClear(ADCSRA,ADEN)` & `bitSet(ADCSRA,ADEN)`,

The interrupt enable bit `bitClear(ADCSRA,ADIE)` & `bitSet(ADCSRA,ADIE)`,

The start conversion bit `bitClear(ADCSRA,ADSC)` & `bitSet(ADCSRA,ADSC)`,

The auto-trigger enable bit `bitClear(ADCSRA,ADATE)` & `bitSet(ADCSRA,ADATE)`,

or do you need some more complicated combination of the bits?

Here's some code where I'm trying to trigger a pulse and  burst of samples and then report back to the host computer:

```
const int numSamples = 20;
const byte startPin = PD0; // start signal (pullup)
const byte pulsePin = PD6; // Normally low
const int pulse_us = 10 ; // output pulse length

int16_t sampleData[numSamples]; 
volatile int sample;
unsigned long t0, t;

// state machine:
typedef enum { STATE_NONE,  // idle
               STATE_SAMPLING, // record ADC
               STATE_DONE, // report data
 } states;
// current state-machine state
volatile states state = STATE_NONE;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(startPin,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(pulsePin,OUTPUT);
  // Clear ADC
  ADCSRA = 0;
  ADCSRB = 0;
  ADMUX = 0;
  ADMUX |= (0b0000 << MUX0); // Choose ADC channel 0
  ADMUX |= (0b01 << REFS0);  // Choose VCC reference voltage
  bitSet(ADMUX,ADLAR);  // ADC left align ADC result into ADCH register

  // sampling rate is [ADC clock] / [prescaler] / [conversion clock cycles]
  // for Arduino Uno ADC clock is 16 MHz and a conversion takes 13 clock cycles
  //ADCSRA |= (0b101 << ADPS0); // /32 : 16M/32/13=38461Hz 26us
  //ADCSRA |= (0b100 << ADPS0); // /16 : 16M/16/13=76923Hz 13us 10 bit precision
  ADCSRA |= (0b011 << ADPS0); // /8  : 16M/8/13=153.8KHz 6.5us low precision
  //ADCSRA |= (0b010 << ADPS0); // /4  : 16M/4/13=307.6KHz 3.2us lower precision
  //ADCSRA |= (0b001 << ADPS0); // /2  : 16M/2/13=615.4Hz 1.6us  bad precision

  ADCSRB |= (0b000 << ADTS0); // Choose free running trigger mode
  
  bitSet(ADCSRA,ADATE); // enable auto trigger mode per ADSCRB:ADTSx 
  bitSet(ADCSRA,ADIE);  // enable interrupts when measurement complete
  bitSet(ADCSRA,ADEN);  // enable ADC
  bitSet(ADCSRA,ADSC);  // start ADC measurements
  
}

ISR(ADC_vect) // Record samples
{
  sampleData[sample++] = ADC;  // read 10bit value from ADC
  if (sample >= numSamples) {
    bitClear(ADCSRA,ADEN); // stop recording
    state = STATE_DONE;
  }
}

void report(){
  t = micros()-t0;  // calculate elapsed time
  Serial.print("Sampling frequency: ");
  Serial.print((float)1000000/t);
  Serial.println(" KHz");
  for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++){
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(sampleData[i]);
    Serial.println();
  }
}

void startSampling(){
  sample = 0;
  t0 = micros();
  digitalWrite(pulsePin,HIGH);
  bitSet(ADCSRA,ADEN); // start ADC
  delayMicroseconds(pulse_us);
  digitalWrite(pulsePin,LOW);
  
}
  
void loop()
{
  switch (state){
    case STATE_NONE:
      if(digitalRead(startPin)==LOW){
        startSampling();
        state = STATE_SAMPLING;
      }
      break;
    case STATE_SAMPLING:
      break;

    case STATE_DONE:
        report();
        state = STATE_NONE;
        break;
    default:
    ;;
  }
}
```

Toggling `ADEN` was my first thought, but `ADIE` seems as if it would be faster, and `ADSC` seems cleanest, if it works to modulate free-running ADC mode.  Which would be fastest and cleanest?

I have a Nano on order, but nothing available for testing right now.

Comment: Using ADIE could give you faulty readings, as you could get an interrupt for a AD-conversion that started before you enabled the interrupts. Using ADEN will make the first conversion take longer, which you might not want. I'd set/clear the ADATE bit. Alternatively, is timing isn't that critical, you could keep the ADC running, and set `sample` back to zero, when you want to start recording a new set of measurements.

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't considered ADATE.  I think I might need to do more than one bit, one to stop the next interrupt, and others to clean up the status on the first capture of the next cycle.  And protect the samples better in the ISR.

Comment: @Gerben -- Yes, letting the ADC run on automatic and toggling the sample recording seemed cleanest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some bumbling around, several bit are important:

```
ADCSRA &= ~(bit(ADATE) | bit (ADSC) | bit (ADIE)); // Disable

ADCSRA |=   bit(ADATE) | bit (ADSC) | bit (ADIE); // Enable
```

The interrupt enable bit `bitClear(ADCSRA,ADIE)` & `bitSet(ADCSRA,ADIE)`, would stop the current ADC measurement from triggering an interrupt event.

The auto-trigger enable bit `bitClear(ADCSRA,ADATE)` & `bitSet(ADCSRA,ADATE)`, triggers a new conversion as soon as the current one finishes.

The start conversion bit `bitClear(ADCSRA,ADSC)` & `bitSet(ADCSRA,ADSC)`, is important for kicking off the first conversion.

The ADC enable bit `bitClear(ADCSRA,ADEN)` & `bitSet(ADCSRA,ADEN)`, turns the ADC subsystem on and off, but there is a bit of a delay on start up.

Ultimately I left free-running automatic ADC enabled and switched the data recording on and off using the `ADCSRA&bit(ADIE)` as a "BURST" state variable.  I think this is good enough for generic impulse-response testing:

```
//: ArduinoPulseADCSample.ino -- Pulse a pin and sample response on ADC
// For Arduino Uno/Nano/mega
// https://github.com/drf5n/foxyPulseInduction_Discrimination/tree/discrimination/ArduinoPulseADCSample
// Adapted from  http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11488&reply=5#reply5
//          and https://github.com/pedvide/ADC/tree/master/examples/analogContinuousRead
//
// This code emits a digital pulse on A1 and collects a sample of highspeed ADC from A0
// It sets up a free-running ADC to quickly record a set of ADC data in
// response to the pulse.  The size of the pulse, pins, number of samples,
// speed of sampling, etc... are all configurable.
// The ADC interrupt handler controls the pulse length and filling the sample buffer
//
// Serial Commands:
//
//  *  Write v and press enter on the serial console to get the value
//  *  Write c and press enter on the serial console to check that the conversion status,
//  *  Write s to stop the conversions, you can restart it writing r.
//  *  Write r to restart the conversions.
//  *  Write p to emit a pulse and record a burst of values
//  *  Write d to see the data recorded during the burst (compatible with SerialPlotter)
//  *  Write m to see metadata about the sample size and interval
//
//  Loopback test with a jumper or RC network between A1 and A2.
//

// Configurables:
const byte adcPin = 0; // A0 -- Pin to read ADC data from
const byte pulsePin = A1; // Next to A0 -- pin to pulse
const byte oneshot_pin = 12; // OC1B pin on Mega, controlled by Timer1
const int pulse_us = 50; // pulse duration
const int numSamples = 20; // sample set
// Change the sampling speed with the prescaler config in setup()


volatile uint16_t samples[numSamples];
volatile int sample = 0;    // position in sample state variable
#define BURST (ADCSRA & bit(ADIE)) /* Sampling burst state variable */
int adcReading;
unsigned long sampleEnd;
unsigned long pulseStart, pulseEnd;



// ########## Timer1 One-shot functions
// The one shot pulses are output on Digital pin OC1B (Arduino Uno D10, Mega D12, Nano D3)
// Modified by Dave Forrest 2020-01-11 for Timer 1
// Based on Josh Levine's Nov 23, 2015 work at https://github.com/bigjosh/TimerShot/blob/master/TimerShot.ino

// Setup the one-shot pulse generator and initialize with a pulse width that is (cycles) clock counts long
#define OSP_SET_WIDTH(cycles) (OCR1B = 0xffff-(cycles-1))
void osp_setup(uint16_t cycles) { // 1 idles, 0xffff never matches, 2-0xfffe makes pulses
  const byte prescaler = 0b010; // Choose /8 for 0.5us resolution
                                // 0b001: /1,      16MHz, 62.5ns resolution, 4ms max 
                                // 0b010: /8,       2MHz,  0.5us resolution, 32ms max
                                // 0b011: /64,    250kHz,  4us  resolution, 263ms max
                                // 0b100: /256,  62.5kHz  16us  resolution, 1.048s max 
                                // 0b101: /1024, 15625Hz, 64us  resolution, 4.194176s max 
  TCCR1B =  0;      // Halt counter by setting clock select bits to 0 (No clock source).
  // This keeps anyhting from happening while we get set up
  TCNT1 = 0x00;     // Start counting at bottom.
  OCR1A = 0;      // Set TOP to 0. This effectively keeps us from counting because the counter just keeps resetting back to 0.
  // We break out of this by manually setting the TCNT higher than 0, in which case it will count all the way up to MAX and then overflow back to 0 and get locked up again.
  OSP_SET_WIDTH(cycles);    // This also makes new OCR values get loaded frm the buffer on every clock cycle.
  TCCR1A = 0b11 << COM1B0  | 0b11 << WGM10; // OC1B=Set on Match, clear on BOTTOM. Mode 15 Fast PWM.
  TCCR1B = (0b11 << WGM12) | (prescaler << CS10); // Start counting now. WGM 15=0b1111  to select Fast PWM mode
  // Setup the OC1B pin for one-shot output:
  //DDRB |= _BV(2);     // Uno Set pin to output (Note that OC1B = GPIO port PB2 = Arduino Uno Digital Pin 10)
  DDRB |= _BV(6);     // Mega Set pin to output (Note that OC1B = GPIO port PB6 = Arduino Mega Digital Pin 12)
  //DDRD |= _BV(3);     // Nano Set pin to output (Note that OC1B = GPIO port PD3 = Arduino Nano Digital Pin 3)
}

// Setup the one-shot pulse generator to idle:
void osp_setup() {
  osp_setup(1);  // 1 puts it in idle mode, 0xffff never triggers, 2-0xfffe produces pulses.
}

// Macro to Fire a one-shot pulse. Use the most recently set width. 
#define OSP_FIRE() (TCNT1 = OCR1B - 1)

// Macro to Test there is currently a pulse still in progress
#define OSP_INPROGRESS() (TCNT1>0)

// Macro to Fire a one-shot pulse with the specififed width.
// Order of operations in calculating m must avoid overflow of the unint16_t.
// TCNT2 starts one count lower than the match value because the chip will block any compare on the cycle after setting a TCNT.
#define OSP_SET_AND_FIRE(cycles) {uint16_t m=0xffff-(cycles-1); noInterrupts();OCR1B=m;TCNT1 =m-1;interrupts();}

// ##########  End of Timer1 One-shot functions
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) { //When overflow...
  //  OCRA1=ICR1; // Constant off in WGM 14, COM1A1:0==0b11
  TCCR1B &= ~(0b111 << CS10) ; //turn off clock
}

//######### ADC Bit-bang for free-running capture of A0
void adc_setup_freerunning(const byte adcPin){
  // set the analog reference (high two bits of ADMUX) and select the
  // channel (low 4 bits).  this also sets ADLAR (left-adjust result)
  // to 0 (the default).
  ADMUX = bit (REFS0) | (adcPin & 0x07);

  // Set the ADC ADPSx prescaler flags to control sampling speed/accuracy
  ADCSRA &= ~(bit (ADPS0) | bit (ADPS1) | bit (ADPS2)); // clear prescaler bits

  //ADCSRA |= 0b001 << ADPS0;   //   2    5 bit, 
  //ADCSRA |= 0b010 << ADPS0;   //   4    6 bit, 5.36us
  //ADCSRA |= 0b011 << ADPS0;   //   8    9 bit, 6.51us
  ADCSRA |= 0b100 << ADPS0;   //  16   10 bit, 13us
  //ADCSRA |= 0b101 << ADPS0;   //  32     10 bit, 26us
  //ADCSRA |= 0b110 << ADPS0;   //  64     10 bit, 52us
  //ADCSRA |= 0b111 << ADPS0;   // 128     10 bit, 104us

  //enable automatic conversions, start them and interrupt on finish
  //ADCSRA |= bit(ADATE) | bit (ADSC) | bit (ADIE);
    ADCSRA |= bit(ADATE) | bit (ADSC) ;

}

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  //pinMode(pulsePin, OUTPUT);
  osp_setup(); // Config Mega Digital 12 for oneshot output
  adc_setup_freerunning(adcPin);

}  // end of setup

// ADC complete ISR
ISR (ADC_vect)  // Store ADC burst values
{
  if (sample >= numSamples) // watch off-by-one
  {
    ADCSRA &= ~bit(ADIE);  // end of sampling burst so stop interrupting
    return;
  }
  // Handle samples
  samples[sample++ ] = ADC;
  //if ( sample == 0){
   // OSP_SET_AND_FIRE(pulse_us * 2); // 
  //}
}  // end of ADC_vect

void loop ()
{
  char c;
  char buff[80];
  unsigned long sampleDuration;
  unsigned long pulseDuration;
  // if last reading finished, process it

  // if we aren't taking a reading, start a new one

  if (Serial.available()) {
    c = Serial.read();
    switch (c) {
      case 'c': // Converting?
        Serial.print("ADCSRA: ");
        Serial.println(ADCSRA, BIN);
        break;
      case 's': // stop conversions
        ADCSRA &= ~(bit (ADSC) | bit (ADIE));
        break;
      case 'r': // restart conversions
        ADCSRA |= bit (ADSC) | bit (ADIE);
        break;
      case 'v':
        adcReading = ADC;
        Serial.print(adcReading);
        Serial.print(' ');
        Serial.print((0.5 + adcReading) * 5.0 / 1024, 4);
        Serial.println(" V");
        break;
      case 'm':
        { 
          unsigned long sampleDuration = sampleEnd - pulseStart;
          unsigned long pulseDuration  = pulseEnd - pulseStart;

          Serial.print("# Pulse: ");
          Serial.print(pulseDuration);
          Serial.print("us and ");
          Serial.print(numSamples);
          Serial.println(" samples.");
          Serial.print("# Time: ");
          Serial.print(sampleDuration);
          Serial.print("us burst of ");
          Serial.print(numSamples);
          Serial.print(" samples at ");
          Serial.print(1.0 * (unsigned long)(sampleEnd - pulseStart) / numSamples);
          Serial.println("us/sample");
          sprintf(buff, " sampleEnd, pulseEnd, pulseStart %02lu : %02lu : %02lu \n", sampleEnd, pulseEnd, pulseStart);
          Serial.print(buff);
          break;
        }
      case 'p': // start pulse
        sample = 0;  // reset sample SV
        pulseStart = micros();
        OSP_SET_AND_FIRE(pulse_us * 2); // pulse outside ISR
        ADCSRA |= bit(ADIF) | bit(ADIE); // clear existing ADInterruptFlag and enable ADC Interrupts
        while(BURST); // block until burst done
        sampleEnd = micros(); // Record times
        pulseEnd = pulseStart + pulse_us;
        break;
      case 'D':
      case 'd': {// report Data
          sampleDuration = sampleEnd - pulseStart;
          for (int ii = 0 ; ii < numSamples ; ii++) {
            if (c == 'D') {
              Serial.print(ii * sampleDuration / numSamples);
              Serial.print(' ');
            }
            Serial.println(samples[ii]);
          }
        }
        break;
      case ' ':
      case '\n':
      case '\r':
        break;
      case 'h':
      case '?':
      default:
        {
          Serial.println("\nArduinoPulseADCSample.in -- Pulse A1 and read a burst of samples from A0\n"
                         "based on serial commands");
          Serial.println("# https://github.com/drf5n/foxyPulseInduction_Discrimination/tree/discrimination/ArduinoPulseADCSample\nCommands: [vcsrpdm] ?");
          Serial.println("Commands:\n"
                         "p: Pulse -- Start a pulse cycle on A1 and record data on A0\n"
                         "d,D: Data -- Dump the data from the last pulse\n"
                         "m: Metadata -- Print the length of pulse, number of samples and rate\n"
                         "v: Voltage -- Conver voltage on A0\n"
                         "c: Converting? -- show ADCSSRA register\n"
                         "h?: Help -- Print this\n"
                        );
        }
        break;
        ;;
    }
  }

  // do other stuff here

}  // end of loop
```

This is the output from the p,m,d commands with a jumper connecting pin 12 to A0 with the /16 prescaler:

```
# Pulse: 50us and 20 samples.
# Time: 276us burst of 20 samples at 13.80us/sample
 sampleEnd, pulseEnd, pulseStart 19270968 : 19270742 : 19270692 
0
1020
1023
1023
1023
3
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

And again with the /8 prescaler.  7.2us/sample or 139Ksamples/sec for 8-9bits isn't bad:

```
# Pulse: 50us and 20 samples.
# Time: 144us burst of 20 samples at 7.20us/sample
 sampleEnd, pulseEnd, pulseStart 4229952 : 4229858 : 4229808 
0
792
1020
1022
1022
1020
1022
1022
1022
305
3
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

ArduinoPulseADCSample.in -- Pulse A1 and read a burst of samples from A0
based on serial commands
# https://github.com/drf5n/foxyPulseInduction_Discrimination/tree/discrimination/ArduinoPulseADCSample
Commands: [vcsrpdm] ?
Commands:
p: Pulse -- Start a pulse cycle on A1 and record data on A0
d,D: Data -- Dump the data from the last pulse
m: Metadata -- Print the length of pulse, number of samples and rate
v: Voltage -- Conver voltage on A0
c: Converting? -- show ADCSRA register
h?: Help -- Print this
```

[image]

Here's an R-C pulse-decay trace on the Serial Plotter with a 22K resistor across A0&12 and a 22uF capacitor from GND to A0.

[image]

Comment: Re “_I left free-running automatic ADC enabled and switched the data recording on and off._”: I think you could do that by toggling just `ADIE`, without touching `ADSC`. Maybe clear the interrupt flag when setting `ADIE`, to avoid getting an interrupt from the last conversion of the previous burst.

Comment: @EdgarBonet -- With the `ADIF=1` trick, `ADCSRA |= bit(ADIF) | bit(ADIE)` would clear any pending interrupt and enable future interrupts.  Sounds good.  I could then use the `ADCSRA & bit(ADIE)` instead of `burst` as my "sampling" state variable and save a test. I've been tweaking things to get down to the 13us/sample threshold that I can get for the ADPS2:0=0b100 /16 1MKz speed that has full 10bit accuracy, but I haven't trimmed the ISR down enough for the /8 clock. I like the pulse control in the ISR for the sync in my use case, but it's sloppy. Maybe pulse on `sample` vs micros() state var?

Comment: ... The pulse length control is sloppy because the pulse is started out of sync with the sampling, and finishes in sync with the sampling.  I like the end synchronization with the samples for my particular application, but it would be nicer to configure a timer as a one-shot and trigger it in the ISR when the `sample == 0`, then you could get higher resolution pulse lengths with both the start and end of the pulse synced with the sampling.   Maybe it could reach 6.5us/sample with 8-9 bit resolution.